# Laptop that only boots after being placed in the freezer once all power is depleted?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hardware-failure

Not an April Fools Day joke!*

I have a Lenovo T500 that will not boot once it looses complete power (battery depleted & AC power loss). The odd thing about the whole issue is that if I place the laptop in the freezer for a couple of hours it boots up just fine and continues to work up until it's disconnected from AC and the battery is again depleted. Then I have to redo the freezer process again to get it to boot up.

My question is what motherboard component(s) may be the culprit of this odd issue?

If it's something I can replace then I would like to do that. I'm not shy when it comes to soldering and have soldered surface mount RAM before in the past on a hobby project.

*References:

http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-70424-dv6000-lights-turn-on-nothing-else
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/254497-28-pavilion-laptop-boot#2595565
http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/toshiba-nb200-wont-boot-492391.html#post2846505

If I don't place the laptop if the freezer and try turning it on I can hear the fan spool up, the lights come on and then it basically resets.  The fan spools again, the lights come on and then it resets.  This happens about 3 times and then it just stays off.  The LCD screen never displays anything though.

Comment: This is an April Fools' Day question? You put the laptop in a freezer for hours?! LOL

Comment: Not criticizing your idea, just wondering how you get to the point where you think, "Hmm, the laptop's not working, I think I'll put it in the freezer for a few hours."

Comment: Also wondering why you let the battery drain all the way out... that's really bad for the battery's longevity

Comment: Actually that's good... Not all the way out, but for as much as possible.

Comment: Nope, it's actually not an April Fools day joke.  I had got to the point where I was trying ANYTHING to get it to boot.  I came across the freezel idea somewhere in my searches.  Let me find a page referencing this.

Comment: The freezer trick is good for a nearly-dead hard drive, but no idea here why it would work for a power issue with a laptop.

Comment: It's never a good idea to put a whole computer into the freezer, except for doing extreme overclocking. Air condensation could create water droplets on the circuits which could cause your computer to fry.

Comment: Well, the laptop was "fried" to begin with.  Putting it in the freezer was a last ditch effort before it went in the trash.

Comment: The only reason why the cold might do the job is having a bad capacitor or some kind of transistor which doesn't function the way it should. You need to find a very very good electrician which has time for this kind of detective work.

Comment: Exactly what happens if you don't "do the freezer process"? Does it behave as though the power button isn't working? Does it crash during boot? Does it fail booting with an error message?

Comment: Jerry do you remove the batttery before stuffing it in the freezer? What happens if you do the Exact same steps for the exact same time, but do not put it in the freezer? If your ready to dissasemble it, couldnt you re-set the thermal goop on the heatsyncs, check the fans, and dust it out, do general maintance, and look around for any bulging caps, or charred silicon components, then test it some, check voltages and do the first more simple stuff?

Comment: @Radoo, the electrician's fee would be several times the price of a new machine...

Comment: @Psycogeek prior to placing it in the freezer I tore it completely apart.  Added Arctic Silver thermal paste to all heatsinks, cleaned all fans and internals.  I was unable to locate any bulging or leaking capacitors, as well as no signs of heat damage.

Comment: @vonbrand, yeah, well, perhaps he has a friend. :)

Comment: Humm... does it work _only_ when just out of the freezer? For how long? (If so, and short, perhaps something made your CPU too temperature sensitive?)

Comment: @vonbrand Once out of the freezer and it boots up then it's fine.  I can shutdown, reboot, ect.  If it looses all power sources (AC & battery) then it's back in the freezer before it'll turn on again.

Comment: That's... intriguing ;) What happens if you try to boot it on AC only, with battery removed?

Comment: @gronostaj Same thing, I can hear the fan spool up, the lights come on and then it basically resets. The fan spools again, the lights come on and then it resets. This happens about 3 times and then it just stays off. The LCD screen never displays anything though.

Comment: Found [a forum thread](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/64361-35-laptop-turns-shuts-seconds-later-laptop) that matches your symptoms pretty closely. Did you try replacing the CMOS battery? The OP of that thread said that replacing it fixed his issue.

Comment: @doug65536 I have not, I'll give that a shot as well.

Comment: I've put a non-functioning HDD in the freezer overnight in a water-tight bag (thanks to internet rumors and my lack of caring for the drive in question). I plugged it in the next day (via IDE->USB dock) and was able to get most of the data off (took about 15 minutes). I've tried since then on multiple occasions but always to no avail.

Comment: @doug65536 Replaced with a new CMOS battery, same deal.  Thanks for the idea though.  Was worth a shot.

Comment: Well I just took it all apart again and tried booting it out of the chassis while adding pressure to varies components again to see if there was a bad solder location and was unable to locate anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I may just buy a used motherboard.  I was able to locate one very cheap.  Just to try though I think I'll do an oven reflow and see if that resolves the issue before trashing the board.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before in some laptops.

Take the battery out.  The laptop should run without the battery in place (with the adapter plugged-in obviously). Then, when your session is complete, shut down. Reinstall the battery and charge as normal.

Comment: This is actually one of the first things I tried, long before the freezer.

Comment: what happens if you leave the battery out overnight and not plugged-in.  Will it boot the next day when plugged-in ?

Comment: Nope, I've let it set for months with no power and it exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact opposite problem with a customer's Vaio laptop..it wouldn't boot unless the unit was warmed, typically in an oven for a few minutes until it was warm to the touch. I took it apart, heated the motherboard in the oven, then powered up the board..and hit various regulator components on the board with freezer spray while the board was running..sprayed one of the caps and the board died. Solution? Replaced the board, since the individual components are not marked and no specs are published.
My suggestion is to use freezer spray on your motherboard and see if the board comes alive. At least this verifies that you have a bad board.

Comment: This sounds like a cold solder joint. Thinking of it, OP's problem could very well be the same, the condensation joining the loose component.

Answer (score -1):

## A capacitor on the power bus

[Freeze Spray is a professional product that exploits this effect](https://gokimco.com/chemtronics-es1052-freeze-spray.html). Capacitance decreases and ESR increases when temperatures drop. Your ESR is failing at room temperature.

That's my guess anyway. Hit the powerbus with freeze spray before you try to turn it on.